# GTK3: version 3.20 to 3.22 update issues (with window decoration)

Tags: opengl, gtk3

I recently updated the GTK3 lib I am using, both on windows and linux, 
from version 3.20 to 3.22, and I noticed some bugs in my application (GTK3 + OpenGL using the GtkGLArea widget) appearing after the update.

The bug, namely the disappearance of window decoration appears after a precise, yet simple, succession of events:

1) screen shot before the bug:

[image]

2) Exporting an image from this window (using a framebuffer for off-screen rendering)

[image]

3) After saving, going back to the main window by closing the dialog box, note that the upper menu bar now appears like if de-activated (grey) but sill works:

[image]

4) ... and when re-sizing / hiding / showing again 'ie. configuring' the window the decoration disappear:

[image]

5) The menu bar still seems to be there and works fine:

[image]

Obviously I looked carefully to the code after the saving action, but what happens remain elusive to me and I do not know what to look for. 
The program does not stop and keeps working fine.

There was absolutely no problem with GTK3 3.20, and the bug appears both on windows and Linux.

What can I do to correct this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Gtk-3 series there have been *many* changes to the CSS system. If you are not using the default Adwaita theme, then probably you have to search for an updated version of the theme you do have installed. It might even be possible that the Adwaita theme wasn't update correctly during your upgrade.

Anyway, nearly all appearance problems are due to changes in the CSS system - Gtk doesn't really occupy itself with the aesthetics anymore.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, I am afraid however that the problem does not come entirely from the update, for windows I installed it from scratch, for Linux I upgraded the entire OS (Fedora) from version 24 to 25 ... I thought every thing was as clean as it could be, but following your suggestion I erased all files in my home folder in case old ones where messing with the configuration ... and it had an effect, as long as I do not resize the window everything remains as it should be (not like point 3) above), however after resize it disappears with the window decorations ...

Comment: ... so it is getting better for Linux, no idea how this can affect the windows version installed from scratch ... maybe there are still files I should clean on Linux to get things working properly, if you have any guess please let me know, I will check windows too ... thanks anyway for the insight !

Comment: Ah well... Distributions like to play with the CSS files to change certain aspects of the 'user experience'. Though files in your home directory can influence the viewing, the actual (global) configuration is done (in my distro) in /usr/share/themes. But don't just delete things there - you might end up without any graphics :-) Check in your appearance setting if Adwaita is selected both in Windows and Linux.